# Laurent series solver

Tags: laurent-series

Given a fractional function containing polynomials in both numerator and denominator; find its Laurent series in all convergence domains. The polynomials are given by its zeros. For example, the function `(z^2+(i-1)z-i)/(z^4-z^2)=((z-1)(z+i))/(z^2(z-1)(z+1))`  is given in the input as:

```
+   1+0i    0-1i
0+0i    0+0i    1+0i    -1+0i
```

The first sign (+ or -) defines the sign of the fraction. The output of the above example is the Laurent series around z0=0 in two convergence domains: |z|<1 and |z|>1.